# Set log-slow-verbosity=explain was not working

Tags: mariadb, slow-log

Trying to enable slow_query with verbosity enabled with different options in Mariadb 10.6.*.
But unable to set option- explain for log-slow-verbosity in mysql session

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/

while we can set other options as query_plan and innoDB in mysql session

```
> set log_slow_verbosity=explain;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'explain' at line 1

> set log_slow_verbosity=query_plan;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.009 sec)

> set log_slow_verbosity=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.038 sec)

> show variables like '%slow%';
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                              |                                                                                                 
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| :::                          |                                    |
| log_slow_verbosity           | query_plan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| slow_query_log               | ON                                                                                                                                   
| slow_query_log_file          | /var/opt/na/log/mysql-1/slow-query.log                                                                                               
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

And while the same is working fine when we set this variable as part of my.cnf file

```
> cat /etc/na/my-1.cnf | grep log-slow
log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain

> show variables like '%log_slow%';
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                              |                                                                                                 
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| log_slow_verbosity           | query_plan,explain                                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Is this option not supported in 10.6 which is not mentioned in the docs or am i missing anything
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-extended-statistics/

Comment: jira.mariadb.org

Comment: Removed mysql tag. This is a feature of MariaDB specifically, and not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Reported the same in MariaDB (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30444) .

> you can omit quotes in some cases. But EXPLAIN is a keyword, that's why it has to be quoted, otherwise it'll be a syntax error.

"explain" option needs quotation marks

```
MariaDB [test]> set log_slow_verbosity='explain';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,000 sec)
 
MariaDB [test]> show variables like 'log_slow_verbosity';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| log_slow_verbosity | explain |
+--------------------+---------+
```